# Text String to Date Time Conversion in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am kind of struggling with dates in Excel. So, here is the case:

I have dates in Column AP in text format as I imported the same from a CSV. All the dates are suppose be DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS.

Using the formula `=DATEVALUE(TEXT(AP2,"DD-MM-YYYY")) + TIMEVALUE (TEXT(AP2,"HH:MM:SS"))` I have been able to convert most of the dates. However, for certain dates like "13-06-2018 00:08:42" or "15-06-2018 00:10:11", the mentioned formula doesn't work. I am getting `#VALUE!`

Need help.. Thanks..

Comment: `DateValue()` uses the default system locale, which means that for a system which is set with the U.S. English locale it expects dates in the form MM/DD/YYYY. So what I would do is convert the string from DD-MM-YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY and feed the result to `DateValue()`. P.S. You should better check whether the dates where the conversion appears to have worked, because they may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting `#VALUE!` when the first field is greater than 12, I surmise that your formula is mixing up the month and date fields. One brute-force way to get the dates is:

```
=DATE(MID(AP2,7,4),MID(AP2,4,2),MID(AP2,1,2))+TIME(MID(AP2,12,2),MID(AP2,15,2),MID(AP2,18,2))
```

Hope that helps